# window.location.href - help redirecting

Tags: javascript, php, window.location

my code is:

```
$movie_id = $_GET['like'];
$temp = "www.hifff.se/details.php?id=" . $movie_id";
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
window.alert('Du får bara lajka en gång per film och dygn. Lajka gärna en annan film eller se filmen igen och återkom imorgon!')
window.location.href='" . $temp . "';
</SCRIPT>");
```

im assuming my setting of $temp is wrong. and therefor not working. but i dont understand what im doing wrong when setting it.
i also heard that this wont work in chrome? and that this:

```
 setTimeout(function(){document.location.href = "page.html;"},500);
```

should. i dont know how i should apply it to my code either.
can someone be kind enough to help me?

Comment: Look at the output from your PHP. You have a pretty obvious syntax error on line two, and could have other problems.

Comment: You don't need the empty double quote after $movie_id in your $temp variable.There may be other problems too.

Comment: Script type="text/javascript",  temp is printed out as variable (add single quotes), two random quotes on the end of assignment of $temp. Maybe more, I'm on the phone :).

Comment: problem wasnt the doublequote, it doesnt add anything at all. problem was the http://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$temp = "http://www.hifff.se/details.php?id=" . $movie_id"";
```

You have to add `http` to your URL in order to perform a correct redirection

Comment: Look at `""` at the end of that string and ask yourself again if that's going to work.

Comment: should like this $movie_id.""

Answer (score 2):

Let's analyze your code together. First line:

`$movie_id = $_GET['like'];`

As you are coding, you learn different design patterns and best practices when you progress. My advice for you is to program defensively. This piece of code might work in the start, but can break easily. Use the `isset` function to check whether the GET variable exists (http://www.php.net/isset).

`$temp = "www.hifff.se/details.php?id=" . $movie_id";`

You are using `PHP's magic quotes`. Magic quotes allow variables inside them and other special characters. PHP will automatically parse them for you, so there's no need to use a concatenation (and the codeblock is even wrong, see quote on the end of the sentence):

`$temp = "www.hifff.se/details.php?id=$movie_id"; // this works.`

**NOTE:** Just found out that magic quotes are deprecated since PHP 5.4. Don't use them if you think you don't need it.

`echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>`

The language attribute has been deprecated since long.. use `type="text/javascript"` instead. This will work, because most new browser use javascript anyway in their `<script>` tags.

Also, it is a general practice to use `"` double quotes for tag attributes. If anyone looks in the source code, then you have single quotes and double quotes everywhere in your HTML. Details, my friend..This will be the result:

`echo ('<script type="text/javascript">`

In the following line, you are calling the `window` object. This object is already in the global scope, so unless you have overwritten this, you don't need to write `window.` anymore. You are also missing a `;` on the end of the alert.

`alert('Du får bara lajka en gång per film och dygn. Lajka gärna en annan film eller se filmen igen och återkom imorgon!');`

Finally, we are at the end. Again, `window` is already `this`, thus it is unnecessary to write the whole thing again. Less is more. You also forget to append `http://` to your `temp` variable. Notice that you use the full `URL` in this situation; it's a better practice to write the location within the website.

You also don't need all those quotes, because the `echo` uses magic quotes, thus exiting the quotes and concatenating the variable is not necessary in this case.

`location.href='$temp';`

Last comment: you are `echo`ing everything in one line.. Does it look organized/neat to you? I think not, it's better to split everything in tiny nice bits, instead of just dumping everything in one line. It will look better and more structured. Any errors you get will be much easier to find. When your code is used or seen by others, it is best to maintain a `programming style`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_style.

---

I would write the code like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['like'])) {
    $temp = "www.hifff.se/details.php?id=" . $_GET['like'];
    $text = 'Du får bara lajka en gång per film och dygn. Lajka gärna en annan film eller se filmen igen och återkom imorgon!';

    echo    '<script type="text/javascript">'
          .     "alert($text); location.href='$temp';"
          . '</script>'
          ;
}
```

Comment: looks like something i really need to read. thanks, i will when i get home. i know about the isset part and that i could post it right into the $temp part. but i use $movie_id 4 or 5 times more in the code and i also post it into a database

Comment: Programming is not just ramming on the computer :), Every line, every character you write has influence on the overall quality of the program, the results, you and the people who will look at the code. It's very difficult to become a good programmer, because every language changes quick. There are also thousands methods and ways to do a simple task. Good luck and have fun programming :)!

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
$temp = "www.hifff.se/details.php?id=" . $movie_id";
```

with

```
$temp = "www.hifff.se/details.php?id=" . $movie_id;
```

Remove doublequotes at the end of the line.